# changing object direction with keys in C#, Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Ive been trying to make this Object move forward by its own and turn left or right in circular fashion in unity using C#, this picture will make it clearer: http://prnt.sc/avmxbn

I was only able to make it move one direction and this is my code so far:

I have no idea, however, how to change left or right directions in circular paths like the picture linked demonstrates. Anyone able to help me? Thank you.